# Memory leak in Node by reference cycle in TCP objects

Tags: node.js, tcp, memory-leaks

My proxy application has a clear memory leak. I took 3 snapshots to see what are the objects allocated between 1 and 2, still not freed after 15 minutes in snapshot 3.

All objects are referenced by Socket and TCP objects. I don't know what is TCP object but I assume it's an node wrapper responsible for TCP connection. TCP objects are referenced back in a cycle and looks like it should be freed by the GC but it's not. Might it be a node issue?

I want to add I make sure I close all the connections within 15 seconds they are opened. I'm also executing netstat looking for open TCP connections. There are only **ESTABLISHED** and **TIME_WAIT** which are always in a **fixed range**, between 500-2000, while **memory consumption only grows** and number of TCP objects in snapshots grow until the application crashes.

How can I debug and fix the leak if I don't know where it's referenced from? The chain ends on **Global handles**?

[image: heap snapshot]

Comment: 1. Sounds like you're opening too many connections. 2. without seeing your code there's a very low chance anyone can help you here

Comment: The code is very complex and it's hard to separate the logic responsible for opening and closing connections. Bottom line is that netstat is not showing increasing number of connections and the leak is only in the node process. My main question is for the debugging techniques